# What is the confidence interval formula that RMISC package in R uses?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I tried figuring out the formula that the RMISC package uses but I wasn't sure, I couldn't find the documentation on it? I tried using the t, and Z statistic but it wasn't giving me the same answer as this package. Any recommendations?

Comment: Confidence interval for what? What function to you use from the package?

Comment: I used the CI function

Comment: This function uses the $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom (just type `CI` in R without the parentheses to see the source code). It yields the same result as the `t.test` function for one sample.

Comment: How come when I used this formula to validate my results, it does not give me the same answer? (abs(qt(0.025,N-1))*sd)/sqrt(N) where N is the samples and sd is the standard deviation, and I'm calculating the  95% confidence interval

Comment: *CI*s are estimated using standard errors, not standard deviations. An interval estimated using standard deviations corresponds to a prediction interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CI` function uses the following formula:

$$
\bar{x} \pm t_{\alpha/2, n-1}\times \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
where $t_{\alpha/2, n-1}$ is the upper $\alpha/2$ critical point of a $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

**Example**

In the following example, I'm drawing 50 random variables from a normal distribution with mean 100 and standard deviation 15 (the values don't matter).

```
library(Rmisc)

set.seed(142857)
x <- rnorm(50, 100, 15) # draw 50 rvs from a normal distribution

xbar <- mean(x)
s <- sd(x)
n <- length(x)

# Calculate the confidence interval by hand
xbar + c(-1, 1)*qt(0.975, n -1)*(s/sqrt(n))
[1]  96.18685 105.28056

# Use the "CI" function from the package
CI(x, 0.95)
    upper      mean     lower 
105.28056 100.73370  96.18685
```

The two confidence limits are exactly the same.

To see what formula the function `CI` uses, you can look at the source code by typing `CI` in to the R console without the parentheses. Like that:

```
CI

function (x, ci = 0.95) 
{
    a <- mean(x)
    s <- sd(x)
    n <- length(x)
    error <- qt(ci + (1 - ci)/2, df = n - 1) * s/sqrt(n)
    return(c(upper = a + error, mean = a, lower = a - error))
}
```

Comment: For small sample sizes, this doesn't hold. For example, with the same seed try: x<-rnorm(2,100,15)

Comment: It does, I'm sorry, I was using the wrong standard deviation. Could please point me to the reference where you found this infomration?

Comment: @Ashti What information do you mean exactly? The derivation of the formula for the confidence interval?

Comment: The refernce saying what RMISC CI is based on- I couldn't find it when I was searching for it

Comment: @Ashti I've updated the answer to show how I got this information.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful